# comm not matching between two log files with identical elements

Tags: linux, comm

I'm trying to use the comm command to compare two logs to see which apps have been installed but not removed. Here's and example of the files:

Installed:

```
2009-03-21 11:43:21 install flex-old:amd54 <none> 3.7.4a-10ubuntu1
2009-03-22 22:55:08 install libubsan0:amd54 <none> 6.3.0-1ubuntu1~14.04
```

Removed:

```
2009-03-24 19:53:49 remove libubsan0:amd54 <none> 6.3.0-1ubuntu1~14.04
```

So the one that would need to be found as different is the "flex-old" line. Here is what I have tried, with some other variations:

```
comm -23 <(sort install.txt) <(sort removed.txt) > difference.txt
```

This outputs all of the installed list, not just the ones that aren't in common with the remove list. I've also tried:

```
comm -3 <(sort install.txt | uniq) <(sort removed.txt | uniq) > what.txt
```

But, this outputs all the apps from both, but with the removed directly under the install.
Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see the [`comm(1)` man page](https://www.google.com/search?q=man+1+comm). The files need to be sorted.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't in fact have *any* matches between `install.txt` and `removed.txt`. Every single line has a different timestamp. Every line in `installed` is different from every line in `removed` because each has the word `install` or `remove`.

Comment: (BTW -- What does this have to do with "check for a specific string"? Your inputs are both files. I don't see what the relationship is between the title and the question -- if you *did* want to search only for a specific string, rather than to compare two sets, `comm` would be the wrong tool for the job).

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter your content to feed only the parts *that could actually be identical* to `comm`.

- The timestamps (first and second columns) are never identical between the two files for the sample input shown.
- The `install` or `remove` lines are never identical between the two files for the sample input shown.

On account of this input *not actually having any identical lines* between the two files, the output described in the question is entirely correct.

---

Emitting only meaningful columns that could be identical, we end up with:

```
comm -23 <(awk '{ print $4 " " $6 }' <install.txt | sort) \
         <(awk '{ print $4 " " $6 }' <removed.txt | sort)
```

See this running at https://ideone.com/IheVRL, and correctly emitting only the (correct) output:

```
flex-old:amd54 3.7.4a-10ubuntu1
```

Comment: Oh, okay, I now see what was wrong with what I was trying. I was focused on only the name identifier part. Is there a way to do it without using awk? I'm just starting out learning, and I haven't used awk yet.

Comment: @rrfeva, "without awk", sure -- `cut` would do, for example. "Without any tool doing the same thing awk is used for here", no. Why not take an opportunity to learn?

Comment: Okay, thank you, maybe I will look more at awk then. I was just wondering if it was possible because I learn best when I focus on one topic for a few problems, then build on that. Thanks again for you help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/set-arithmetic/ .

I find it a bit easier and slightly more powerful than comm.  It does not require any sorting.

Full disclosure: I wrote it.

HTH.

Comment: I'm curious about how some of the algorithmic challenges are handled. `comm` can operate in constant memory and O(n) time if inputs are pre-sorted, or when coupled with GNU `sort` can do parallel merge sorts backed by temporary files on-disk to be able to operate on contents larger than fit in RAM, without depending on virtual memory / swap space being available. Would you mind expanding a bit on how your tool fares in the same circumstances?

Comment: Good question.  comm itself is O(1) memory and O(n+m) time.  However, comm requires sorted inputs, so its rarely used all by itself - this increases the time to O(nlogn + mlogm).  set-arithmetic is O(n+m) memory and O(n+m) time, and does not need (or benefit from) a sort step.

Comment: *nod* -- so you're trading off against space for time; pending analysis of how the constant factors differ based on implementation choices, that might often come out well. I will note that it's often possible to sort a dataset *once*, and then reuse it -- in my real-world use cases for `comm`, I'm often comparing one large fixed dataset (which I sorted once, at creation time) against a smaller dynamic one (which is relatively cheap to sort at time-of-use). Under those circumstances, loading both sets into RAM would definitely be a step back.